# Firebase Exceptions handling on create user by email

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

How to handle errors in the new Firebase sdk for authentication? In the previous versions i can find the OnAuthenticationError method and it gives FirebaseException error but in the new verison i dont see such method. Lets say i create a user by email password,for some reason  exception occurs . The only way i can see to grab this exception is the task.getException.getMessage() and with this message i check for various error messages and then in turn get the error which occured. Please suggest a better method or correct me if i m missing something

Answer (score 2):

**The main exceptions:**

```
firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass )
      .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
           @Override
           public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
           if(task.isSuccessful())
               {
                 //--If success        
 }else if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException) 
 {                           
     //If email already registered.

 }else if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
     //If email are in incorret  format    

 }else if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException) {
        //if password not 'stronger'                    
 }else
 {
    //OTHER THING
 }
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In the new Firebase a lot of methods return a so-called [`Task`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task). If you've used promises in JavaScript before, you'll find they're very similar.

On the task, you can get a few callbacks:

- a success listener, which gets invoked once the task succeeds
- a failure listener, which gets invoked once the task fails
- a completion listener, which gets invoked once the task completes (successfully or not)

In your case you're looking for a failure in [creating a user](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#public-methods), so:

```
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create user", e);
        }
    });
```

The exception will be a subclass of [`FirebaseAuthException`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthException), which means you can call `getErrorCode()` on it. This returns an error code. It's indeed a string, but of a form `auth/error` which can be easily captured in a switch case.

Also see the [documentation on creating a user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth#sign_in_a_user_with_an_email_address_and_password) for a sample that uses a completion listener.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If i add onFailureListener then in the overriden  onFailure method i get a parameter java 'Exception' in which i can get only the error message, with this message i have to iterate over all several predefined strings by me to handle this exception. I was looking for a better method as of old firebase sdk.

Comment: I indeed had the signature wrong. I now captured it in Android Studio for you convenience. The 2.x SDK had a numeric error code. Handling all string error codes isn't much different.