# FireBase Auth createUserWithEmailAndPassword().then() not working

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I am working on an android application that involves user firebase auth for user sign up. The sign up works but I want to add username to database by implementing it in .then() but my android studio keeps giving "unresolved method then(?)". I am also using catch but that seems to work fine.The code I am writing is as following where firebaseAuth is an object of type FirebaseAuth:

```
            firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
                .then( (u) => {
                        //Implementation of then
                })
                .catch(error => {
                switch (error.code) {
                    case 'auth/email-already-in-use':
                        EmailWarning.setText("Email already in use");
                    case 'auth/invalid-email':
                        EmailWarning.setText("Invalid Email");
                    case 'auth/weak-password':
                        PasswordWarning.setText("Password should be 8 characters or longer");
                    default:
                        PasswordWarning.setText("Error during sign up");
                }
        });
```

I found a similar problem in following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38511285/firebase-v3-createuserwithemailandpassword-then-promise) but even after trying this, it's not working.

I looked further into the firebase documentation and found another implementation which uses on complete listener [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start) however the error codes described in this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.auth.Auth#createuserwithemailandpassword) doesn't seem to work with it.

Update 1:
I ended up implementing on complete listener as following:

```
            firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                                    .setDisplayName(Username)
                                    .build();

                            user.updateProfile(profileUpdates);
                        }
                        else {
                            // If sign up fails, display a message to the user.
                            switch (task.getException()) {
                                case "auth/email-already-in-use":
                                    EmailWarning.setText("Email already in use");
                                case "auth/invalid-email":
                                    EmailWarning.setText("Invalid Email");
                                case "auth/weak-password":
                                    PasswordWarning.setText("Password should be 8 characters or longer");
                                default:
                                    PasswordWarning.setText("Error during sign up");
                            }
                        }

                    }
                });
```

Now the user adding part works fine but the exception handler doesn't work with strings so I can't find a way to work with error codes given on firebase documentation

Comment: I think you want `task.getError()`, I dont think `task.getException()` exists -> https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/io/fabric/sdk/android/fabric/services/concurrency/Task?hl=en

Comment: and `isFinished()` instead of `isSuccessful()` - `isFinished()` should only be called if it finishes without error, from same doc link above.

Comment: I would log `task.getError()` to make sure you know what the strings are, you are probably only getting into the error block because `isSuccessful()` isn't a function.

Comment: `task.getError()` will return a `Throwable` -> https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/io/fabric/sdk/android/fabric/InitializationException - it looks like you can use `getMessage()` or `toString()` to get string representations of the error. To get the actual `Throwable` you can use `getCause()` - this would return an exception object like `InitializationException`, and if you know which exceptions are possible you can use `==` with those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wasn't able to find a solution to .then() issue but after searching more into getExceptions() I found a solution at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45702440/). Now my current implementation looks as following:

```
            firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                                    .setDisplayName(Username)
                                    .build();

                            user.updateProfile(profileUpdates);

                            OpenApp();
                        }
                        else {
                            // If sign up fails, display a message to the user.

                            String errorCode = ((FirebaseAuthException) task.getException()).getErrorCode();
                                if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException)
                                    EmailWarning.setText("Email already in use");
                                else if(task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException)
                                    EmailWarning.setText("Invalid Email");
                                else if(task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException)
                                    PasswordWarning.setText("Password should be 8 characters or longer");
                                else
                                    PasswordWarning.setText("Error during sign up");
                            }
                        }
                });
```

Also found another alternate implementation by try catch and and getException().getErrorCode() [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37859582/how-to-catch-a-firebase-auth-specific-exceptions).

Answer (score 0):

I found this in the docs for you:

```
firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:success");
                FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                updateUI(user);
            } else {
                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                Log.w(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                Toast.makeText(EmailPasswordActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                updateUI(null);
            }

            // ...
        }
    });
```

Looks like you need to use `.addOnCompleteListener`

Doc -> https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth

Comment: I tried this one, I am able to resolve the username adding issues with it but the error codes described in the other firebase document (which I am using in catch) doesn't work with it or I am unable to figure out right format of condition for it

Comment: show me what you tried, you can edit your post with the additional info

Comment: OK, I added the new implementation

Answer (score 0):

I have found my issue with the help of (task.getException())
So I hope maybe it will helpful for resolving your issue.

```
firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
               
            } else {

               Log.d("---->",""+task.getException());
            }

           
        }
    });
```